# Facing error in Dagger while build the application

Tags: dagger-2, dagger

getting a Gradle error while building an android app.

following error:

> Program type already present: dagger.Reusable

Any kind of help would be highly appreciated.

**app/Gradle**

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    implementation project(':transport')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0'
    compile files('libs/org.eclipse.paho.android.service-1.1.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3-1.1.1.jar')
    compile 'com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:3.2.0'
    implementation ('com.google.dagger:dagger:2.23'){
        exclude group: "javax.inject", module: "javax.inject"
    }
    annotationProcessor ("com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.23"){
//        exclude group: "javax.inject", module: "javax.inject"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not supposed to use Dagger 2 dependencies in the `implementation` scope, as is done in your snippet.

Problematic lines:

```
implementation ('com.google.dagger:dagger:2.23'){
        exclude group: "javax.inject", module: "javax.inject"
}
```

See: https://github.com/google/dagger/issues/1179